# zakat payment on accumulated money for more than one year with out adding on it

Tags: zakat

Aselamalykum, 
i do have 10k USD  accumulated  in ramedan 2014. i paied zakat in 2015 ramedan for the first time. but the amount remains the same therefore should i pay for the second year zakah in 2016?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. The Zakat is a yearly payment done on the total savings you have if that savings went above the limit "Nisab".

Reference:
http://islamqa.info/en/93414